# Shipping logistics on Shopify platform

Tags: e-commerce

**Please note:** although I mention Shopify here, and would prefer a solution provided by the Shopify platform, I think this question is applicable to any small retail site and the answer may very well lie in something homegrown.

---

I am trying to help a buddy out that has an emerging (and surprisingly successful) mom-and-pop shop retail website. He is a world-class ["grip athlete"](https://www.gripsport.org/) that holds several world records for lifting ridiculous things off the ground with nothing more than an iron grip. His hands are like hydraulic presses.

He fabricates all of his own "grip implements" (weird looking handles and widgets that you attach weights to for special kinds of grip lifts) and sells them on his Shopify website. In just over a year he already has had more than 1200 orders!

His problem lies in shipping logistics. I bought something from him recently and noticed that he charged my one time for the item I purchased from him, and then he *invoiced* me a separate charge for $5.00. When I asked him he told me this:

> "*Because there is no accurate way to figure out exactly the size of the package when people buy multiple items. Does it fit in a medium flat rate or a large flat rate or is it cheaper to go cubic rate or even ups? Either I get screwed or the customer does so to accurately calculate it i package it first and then determine cost. Single items are easy but when someone buys 3+ items of various sizes then the computer doesnt do it accurately...I figure out the cheapest way to send it and then charge the customer that.*"

So what he's had to do...for all 1200 orders (yikes) is:

1. For each order, fabricate all the items that were purchased and already paid for
2. Manually play around with different shipping options/rates/etc. until he finds the cheapest way to send it to his customer
3. Ship it (using the manually-optimized method mentioned above)
4. Invoice the customer for the shipping cost he already paid for it :-/

I'm wondering if there are any services/tools out there that keep up to date mail carrier rates and packaging options and helps figure out the cheapest solution for my buddy. Does anything out there exist like this? Does Shopify have any built-in tools for doing this type of determination?

Comment: Surely by the time he's shipped 1200 orders your buddy has got a good handle on the shipping costs for 95% of orders ?  And can afford to take a punt on the remainder ?  Not sure I see this as needing anything more sophisticated than a good memory (or if you must have a software solution, a spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Either I get screwed or the customer does

I choose *you* customer!

Comment: This is the industry standard answer.